# Почему requests.get() получает только 30 репозиториев с Гитхаба Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, github, github-api

Мне нужно получить названия всех репозиториев Твиттера на Гитхабе. Репозиториев больше 100, но в `request` попадает только первые 30. Как это исправить, не используя клинта для Гитхаба (то есть без `g = Github()` и т.д.)?

```py
url = f'https://api.github.com/orgs/Twitter/repos'
request = requests.get(url).json()
result = []
for element in request:
    result.append(element['full_name'])
```

Нашел на сайте апи Гитхаба такие параметры.[image]
`page`, вроде, то, что нужно, но как это добавить в `requests.get(url)`?

Comment: `?page=2` Очевидно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получает 30, потому что так и написано

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрашивайте постранично, и укажите что за раз вам надо 100

> https://api.github.com/orgs/Twitter/repos?per_page=100

и далее пока будет что-то отдавать...

> https://api.github.com/orgs/Twitter/repos?per_page=100&page=2

> https://api.github.com/orgs/Twitter/repos?per_page=100&page=3 ...